# reversing array data from * to empty and empty to *

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d

So I have created a 2D Array called pixels. I have written a method to flip the array over a vertical axis and rotate the array once by 90 degrees. I know it is simple, and I am probably overlooking something simple, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to reverse data in the array. The array hold blank values and * values to print a picture. I need to create a method that will reverse all * to empty and all empty spaces to *.

Yes this is homework (lab actually) and if you explain to me how the method would work I am sure I can write it on my own. Just looking for some pointers here. Thanks.

EDIT:

my code that won't work, operand mismatch error char[][] and char

```
   public void invert ( ){

    if (pixels == '*'){

        pixels = ' ';
    }
    else{
        pixels = '*';
    }


     }
```

code that creates the array:

```
               private char[][] pixels = 
    {  { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
        { ' ', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', ' ', ' ' },
        { ' ', '*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
        { ' ', '*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*', ' ' },
        { ' ', '*', '*', '*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
        { ' ', '*', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*', ' ', ' ' },
        { ' ', '*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*' },
        { ' ', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', ' ', ' ' }, 
        { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' } };
```

Comment: What's wrong with `if (pixel == '*') pixel = ' '; else pixel = '*';`??

Comment: I created the array as private char[][] pixels, so the if statement is throwing an incompatible operand types char[][] and char. there is probably a way around it but I am drawing a blank.

Comment: Show some code, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to walk the matrix, not simply use it in the conditional clause. It seems to me that `pixels` is of type `char[][]`.

You need to iterate over it and, for each element, do something like:

```
if (pixels[i][j] == '*'){
    pixels[i][j] = ' ';
}
else{
    pixels[i][j] = '*';
}
```

, where `i` and `j` are the current coordinates.

Comment: Thank you, I wrote a nested for loop e.g. for int i, and then for int j. seems to work ok.